# New Data Type but what does it mean?

Tags: haskell

just found a new datatype, but I absolutly don't get what it actually means.

```
data Gate = Gate (Bool->Bool->Bool)
```

**Output**

```
let a = Gate
a :: (Bool->Bool->Bool)->Gate
```

First I thought it says that I need two Bools to get a new one, but the :t a says that I need three, doens't it?

Comment: Are you talking about the `Gate` or `a`?

Comment: I am talking about the data Gate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Gate` is two things: a type, and a constructor that creates a value of that type. The purpose of the type is to wrap functions of type `Bool -> Bool -> Bool`. For example:

```
> data Gate = Gate (Bool->Bool->Bool)
> andGate = Gate (&&)
> orGate = Gate (||)
```

The `Gate` data constructor doesn't take `Bool` values; it takes a single *function* of type `Bool -> Bool -> Bool` and "lifts" it into the `Gate` type.

In order to *do* anything with such a function, you need some way to extract the function from its wrapper.

```
> getFunc (Gate f) = f
> (getFunc andGate) True False
False
```

Normally, for performance reasons, you would define a type like this using `newtype`, not `data`:

```
newtype Gate = Gate (Bool -> Bool -> Bool)
```

Practically speaking, the types are the same, but the `newtype` is more efficient because internally the wrapper will be stripped for you. In either case, you would only define a new type if you wanted to create some specific typeclass instances for `Gate`; otherwise, you could just define a type alias such as

```
type Gate = Bool -> Bool -> Bool
```

Answer (score 4):

`data Gate = Gate (Bool->Bool->Bool)` defines both a type `Gate` and a constructor of that type, also named `Gate`.

When you do `let a = Gate`, Haskell assumes you mean the `Gate` constructor as that's what `let` allows you to bind as a value.

The type of the `Gate` constructor is that of a function that will take a value of type `Bool->Bool->Bool` and return a value of *type* `Gate`.

You could do something like `data Gate = MakeGate (Bool -> Bool -> Bool)` to highlight the difference

Comment: Thanks, now I know what a constructor is. But what does "MakeGate :: (Bool->Bool->Bool) -> Gate mean? Specially the Gate at the end.

Comment: @Peek It means `MakeGate` returns a value of type `Gate`.